# AVR variable order in section

Tags: gcc, avr

Consider the following code:

```
#define VER __attribute__((section(".version")))
const uint8_t VER major=0x01;
const uint8_t VER minor=0x03;
const uint8_t VER patch=0x0a;
const uint8_t VER build=0x00;
```

When compiled with avr-gcc 4.3 all the variables are in order of declaration in output hex file.

When compiled with avr-gcc 4.7 all the variables are in reverse order in output hex file.

Is there any compiler/linker option to unify this behavior?

Comment: Why can't you declare it as a single array?

Comment: If this is the only way, I'll have to do this. But I have similar bunch of variables of different types worth 1k of eeprom memory. So I would like to go some other way. If it exists.

Answer (score 1):

> When compiled with avr-gcc 4.3 all the variables are in order of declaration in output hex file. 
> When compiled with avr-gcc 4.7 all the variables are in reverse order in output hex file.

There is no specified order in which objects are placed into input sections, so Binutils internals — for example how sections and objects are represented internally — might affect their ordering.

> Is there any compiler/linker option to unify this behavior?

There are several ways:

- You can advise in the linker description file, that objects are sorted according to their name or their alignment, see `SORT_BY_NAME` and `SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT` in the [Binutils documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Wildcards.html).
- Similar can be achieved during link by means of option `-Wl,--sort-sections,alignment` resp. with parameter `name`.
- You can add respective section to the linker script, like

  ```
  *(.version.major)
  *(.version.minor)
  *(.version.patch)
  *(.version.build)
  KEEP(*(.version*))
  ```

  which has the additional benefit that it's no more [orphan sections](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Orphan-Sections.html).
- Do it on C/C++ level, like for example by putting things into a composite:

  ```cpp
  typedef struct
  {
      uint8_t major, minor, patch, built;
  } version_t

  __attribute__((__used__, __section__(".version")))
  const version_t version = { 0x1, 0x3, 0xa, 0x0 };
  ```